# Get Issuer certificate from certificate by OpenSSL C++

Tags: c++, openssl

I want to Get Issuer Certificate from Certificate using OpenSSL as a following command.

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -issuer -out issuer.pem
```

What's the method that is used to get the issuer Certificate?

Comment: I don't think even the command you're providing will give what you want with a straight up x509 certificate. It *may* with a PEM bundle (both issuer and final are in the same bundle). Are regular x509 certificate includes the AKI as an extension and the signature performed by said-same. The actual issuer's certificate isn't part of the equation.

Comment: I have used this command and issuer certificate is extracted. i want this in ocsp for crl

Comment: thanks @WhozCraig, i have solved it.

Comment: I disagree. The `-issuer` command options just emits the issuer's *distinguished name*. The actual certificate that is emitted from a regular single X509 PEM file is the same one you put in. I sure hope you're not relying on the certificate that comes out of what you showed as the issuer's cert, because it definitely is **not**.

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking for the x509 command implementation (openssl 1.1.0h), you should look at apps\x509.c@621

```
for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (issuer == i) {
        print_name(out, "issuer=", X509_get_issuer_name(x), nmflag);
    } else if (subject == i) {
```